# How tree.sort really works?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the root node with the unsorted children nodes.
I use the `tree.nodes(treeData)` to get the nodes list and build a hierarchical list and I want it to be sorted. See example code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfKUh/1/) or below:

```js
/// define data
var treeData = {
    name: 'root',
    children: [
        { name: 1 },
        { name: 5 },
        { name: 2 },
        { name: 6 },
        { name: 4 },
        { name: 3, children: [ {name: 33 }, {name: 31 }, {name: 32 } ] },
        { name: 7 }
    ]
};

/// init tree
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); });
var nodes = tree.nodes(treeData); // nodes unsorted now
// uncomment this to get sorted nodes
// nodes = tree.nodes(treeData);

/// build hierarchy
var li = d3.select('ul').selectAll('li').data(nodes);
li.enter().append('li')
    .html(function(d) {
        return Array(d.depth).join('∣  ') + (d.depth ? '↳ ' : '') + "<b>"+d.name+"</b>" + " x: " + Math.round(d.x*100)/100 });
```

When `tree.sort()` is defined then `treeData.children` array is sorted but `tree.nodes(treeData)` returns the unsorted array of nodes.

Also I discovered that if I call `tree.nodes()` twice then it returns sorted nodes:

```
nodes = tree.nodes(treeData) // returns unsorted: 1, 5, 2... but treeData.children is now sorted
nodes = tree.nodes(treeData) // returns sorted: 1, 2, 3...
```

It seems that `tree.sort()` affects the `treeData.children` array and the `node.x` and `node.y` values but not does not affect the nodes order in the result of `tree.nodes()` function.

**So the question is what the proper way of using `tree.sort()` with `tree.nodes()`?**

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Do you think that `tree.nodes(treeData)` should return sorted nodes?

Comment: I would expect it to in this context, yes.

Answer (score 1):

`d3.layout.tree().sort()` is part of `d3.layout.hiearchy()`.

In version `3.5.6` (the one I looked at), the `d3.layout.hierarchy` function builds an array of nodes breadth-first from the `root` tree provided, in the order already defined by `node.children`.

Every node of the tree is inserted into the returned node array in this order.

After the array is built, then the `root` tree is sorted by `d3_layout_hierarchyVisitAfter`, but this only sorts the tree's `node.children` and not the node array.

The node array itself **is never sorted**. The order of nodes in the node array is based on the order of the `root` tree and its `node.children` order. Hence the suggestions to sort it first (or why calling `d3.layout.tree().sort()` a second time works - because the children have been sorted now)

Looking at the [D3 4.x documentation for sort](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#node_sort) the last thing it says is

> You must call node.sort before invoking a hierarchical layout if you
>   want the new sort order to affect the layout; see node.sum for an
>   example.

So while the 3 documentation doesn't explicitly say this, it looks like the code is written that way.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/fa55eead411a3c1b01703cb1ddfd59ccc0b23124/src/selection/sort.js), d3 only reproduces the [array sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) ...

So the catch is that you need to sort them first ... them "append" to the tree.

Check out the solution: http://jsbin.com/sonil/1/edit

```
////sort the data
treeData.children.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); });
/// init tree
var tree = d3.layout.tree();//.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); });
var nodes = tree.nodes(treeData); // nodes sorted
```

Comment: Manually sort the treeData is not a problem for me. I am curious how to use `tree.sort()` properly.

Comment: I could not find no good way to use tree.sort ... the docs aren't really helpful about it ... I really suggest you go for the manual ordering since it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### you can sort hierarchical  data by

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition().value(function(d) { return d.size; });

partition(data);
```

by this it will share data memory always